# having trouble with getaddrinfo()

Tags: 14.04, networking, postfix, libraries

I have a 14.04 LTS server installation.  It is relatively new.  It is up to date on its patches.  I'm running postfix on it and I noticed that the SMTP server was having trouble resolving `delivery.mailspamprotection.com` (siteground's outgoing mail server.).

When I use `dig` I get all of the addresses (about 30 of them). I have a small C program that uses libc6's `getaddrinfo()` function.  That returns only one address.  I am running my own recursing nameserver (pdns-recursor) which seems to be running fine.  I've run queries against it from other servers and it's returning the correct information.  I've also run queries from this server to different recursors using `dig` and I get the correct information.

However, when I run the little program that uses the libc6 resolver library (`getaddrinfo()`), I only get one address back.  The `host.conf` setting of `multi on` is set.  I have `order bind,hosts`, `multi on`, `no-spoof  on`   .

I have another 14.04 LTS host that works fine. libc6 version `2.19-0ubuntu6.7`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The manpage says `getaddrinfo` configuration is in `/etc/gai.conf`. Do both servers have the same `/etc/gai.conf`?

Comment: That changes how the addresses are sorted and precedence.  It doesn't say anything about whether multiple addresses or a single address are returned.

Comment: [SOLVED] The problem was in the /etc/nsswitch.conf.  changed the line "hosts:     files dns" to "hosts:     dns files" and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

[SOLVED] The problem was in the "/etc/nsswitch.conf". I changed the line "hosts: files dns" to "hosts: dns files" and that solved the problem.

Further, in a note of embarrassment, the host in question was also in the "/etc/hosts" file.  I don't remember doing that, so it was a self inflicted problem.